# RedirectMatch and Redirect interfering with each other

Tags: redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I have the following lines in my `.htaccess` (there are other lines but these two are next to each other)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/datingstories https://example.com/blog/category/relationships/datingstories/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ showprofile.php?username=$1
```

- There is a WordPress blog component to the site (under `/blog`) as well as a
  membership and profile pages built outside of WordPress.
- The first line is a simpler way to access a specific set of blogs in a sub-category i.e. `https://example.com/datingstories` translates to the dating sub-category of the blog. This is also shared externally (which is why I wanted the shorter URL)
- The second line translates sitename/username to
  `sitename/showprofile.php?username=username`. There are member profile
  pages on the site and the URL is simplified (i.e.
  `https://example.com/frank` redirects to `https://example.com/showprofile.php?username=frank`). However, the URL on the browser shows `https://example.com/frank`

The issue is when `https://example.com/datingstories` is click/linked to, the resulting URL is `https://example.com/blog/category/relationships/datingstories/?username=dating`

While the page still loads, is there any way of preventing the `?username=dating` from showing as part of the resulting URL. I think the second `.htaccess` rule is being applied but I am not sure how since `showprofile.php` is not showing up in the resulting URL.

Also, ideally, it would be great if the resulting page shows the shorter URL rather than the longer one.

I appreciate your time in looking and responding to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RedirectMatch and Redirect interfering with each other

In the example you've given, `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) are "interfering with each other", not `Redirect`. `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive, that works *with* `RedirectMatch` - so you wouldn't necessarily expect these to conflict in this way.

As mentioned above, `RewriteRule` is a mod_rewrite directive, whereas `RedirectMatch` (and `Redirect`) are mod_alias directives. Different Apache modules execute independently and at different times during the request, regardless of the apparent order in your `.htaccess` file. In the case of mod_alias and mod_rewrite, mod_rewrite always executes *first*.

So, in your example, the `RewriteRule` (2nd directive) will be processed *before* the `RedirectMatch` directive that precedes it - since they both match the URL `/datingstories`. Processing then continues through the file and the whole process starts over for a 2nd pass, when the first mod_alias `RedirectMatch` *redirects* the URL (`RedirectMatch` matches against the URL in the request, not the rewritten URL. So, this matches `/datingstories` again, not `showprofile.php` - the rewritten URL). This replaces the rewritten URL-path (`showprofile.php`) but keeps the query string (`?username=dating`). (However, it's not clear from the directives you posted, why `datingstories` would get truncated to `dating` in the URL parameter - maybe there is a conflict with other directives.) The earlier *rewrite* is converted to an *external redirect* after the 301 HTTP status is applied.

The lesson here is that you should never mix *redirects / rewrites* from both modules - in order to avoid confusing conflicts such as this. Since WordPress uses mod_rewrite for its front-controller, you would ideally use mod_rewrite throughout. So, you should convert any mod_alias `RedirectMatch` (and `Redirect`) directives to use mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` instead.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^datingstories /blog/category/relationships/datingstories/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ showprofile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

And don't neglect the `L` flag - to stop further processing (current pass through the file) when required.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reasoning around the response. I learned more about mod_alias and mod_rewrite. Unfortunately, the example did not work for me. What ended up happening is it thinks that https://example.com/datingstories is a member profile and tries to show the page associated with that member (second rewrite) but since that member does not exist, it shows the resulting 'does not exists' page according to the script. I am experimenting with a RewriteCond right before the second line but no success just yet.

Comment: I added the following just before the second rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thedatinggam` to prevent the rule from applying for this URL. This seemed to work as it no longer re-directs to the 'does not exists' page. I also changed the order of the original 2 rules around so it now looks likes this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thedatinggam` 
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ showprofile.php?username=$1 [L]` 
`RewriteRule ^/thedatinggam /blog/category/relationships/thedatinggam/ [R=301,L]`
However, the first rule does not seem to work, I now get a 404 error.

Comment: I am using the 'thedatinggam' in place of 'datingstories' (in comment above). I don't think it makes a difference as I also tried it with the original with the same result.

Comment: Given just the two directives above then it should not be possible for the 2nd `RewriteRule` to be processed for a `/datingstories` request. So, if it is being seen as a "member profile", then either _something else_ is doing that (a conflict with other directives perhaps) or you are seeing a cached response? The `RewriteCond` directive would only be required if you did change the order of these rules. But changing the order does not seem to make sense (in fact, that would result in a similar problem you had in the beginning) - you should have the most specific rules _first_.

Comment: Presumably these directives are _before_ the WordPress front-controller?

Comment: Thank you for all the details in your answers - it has really help debug the problem. I reverted back to the order as you suggested. It was a problem with the extra '/'.   'RedirectBase /' was used prior and the extra '/' in '^/datingstories' in effect created a URL that does not exist e.g. https://example.com//datingstories

Comment: Glad you got it working. Incidentally, `^/datingstories` (with a slash prefix) would be required for the _pattern_ if using `RedirectMatch`, but not if using `RewriteRule`, as above (the directory-prefix is _removed_). (Although this has nothing to do with the `RewriteBase` directive.)